# как поставить цвет для border из инпут который вводит пользователь

Tags: javascript

у меня есть `border` и для него нужно поставить цвет который пользователь вводит через `input` я пытался сделать только на `js` и прошу помогите мне на `js` я 3 дня уже пытаюсь это сделать

```
 <script>
        var head = document.getElementById('header');
        var headd = document.getElementById("head");
        var main = document.getElementById("main");
        var mainn = document.getElementById("mainer");
        var foot = document.getElementById("foot");
        var foott = document.getElementById("footer");
        var input = document.getElementById("color");
        var add = document.getElementById("add");
        var a = document.getElementById("a");
        var aa = document.getElementById("aa");
        var pre = document.getElementById("pre");
        var pree = document.getElementById("pree");
        var p = document.getElementById("p");
        var pp = document.getElementById("pp");
        headd.style.display = "none";
        foott.style.display = "none";
        function showHeadd(){
          headd.style.display = "block"; 
          headd.style.borderColor = "input.value";
        }
        function showMain(){
            mainn.style.border = "3px solid input.value";

        }
        function showFoot(){
            foott.style.display = "block"; 
            foott.style.border = "3px solid red";
        }
        function showAdd(){
            pre.style.display = "inline";
            a.style.display = "inline";
            p.style.display = "inline";
        }

        function showPre(){
            pree.style.display = "block"
        }
        function showA(){
            aa.style.display = "inline"
        }
        function showP(){
            pp.style.display = "block"
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: ловите код поцаны

Comment: И... где вы вызываете ваши функции? Каким образом ваш код реагирует на вводимые в input данные? Я не нашёл

Comment: `mainn.style.border = "3px solid input.value";`

Comment: @Мишаня `input.value` - переменная, и не может находится внутри строки. Это дело можно записать в виде `mainn.style.border = "3px solid " +  input.value;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А с какого по счету id надоест добавлять переменные с этими id?) Можно всем элементам, которые должны менять цвет рамки - дать общий класс, и менять цвет элементов с этим классом. А выбор цвета можно было организовать через `input type="color"` вместо ручного ввода.

```js
let pick = document.getElementById('pick-border');

pick.addEventListener('change', function(){
  let border = document.querySelectorAll('.js-border');
  for( let i = 0; i < border.length; i++ ){
    border[i].style.borderColor = this.value;
  }
});
```

```css
.js-border {
  border: 3px solid red;
  padding: 5px; margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input id="pick-border">

<div class="js-border"> bubu </div>

<div class="js-border"> bubu </div>

<div class="js-border"> bubu </div>

<div class="js-border"> bubu </div>
```

Comment: нужно через инпут

Comment: @Мишаня всего-то надо было убрать type="color"